# how this code works to calculate sizeof of datatype?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define My_Sizeof(type) ((char*)((type*)0 +1) - (char*)(type*)0)
void main()
{
    char a='1';
    int b=My_Sizeof(int);
    printf("size is %d",b);
    _getch();
}
```

// can anybody help me to understand wt the macro does to calculate sizeof char datatype ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break it down:

```
#define My_Sizeof(type) ((char*)((type*)0 +1) - (char*)(type*)0)
```

`(char*)(type*)0` is zero

`(type*)0 +1` does pointer arithmetic using pointers of type `(type *)`, so `(type *)0 + 1` will be a pointer of offset exactly `0 + 1 * sizeof(type) = sizeof(type)` bytes

When the difference is taken as `(type *)` the difference is `1`.  When the difference is taken with both types `(char *)`, the difference is `sizeof(T) - 0 = sizeof(T)`

Answer (score 3):

Breaking it up into bite-sized pieces, the following pseudo-function achieves the same result:

```
size_t My_Sizeof(type) {
    type* elem0 = (type*)0;
    type* elem1 = (type*)0 + 1;
    char* elem0_addr = (char*)elem0;
    char* elem1_addr = (char*)elem1;
    return elem1_addr - elem0_addr;
}
```

The expression computes the addresses of the elements in a two-element array nominally located at the null pointer address. It then casts both address to char* and subtracts, which yields the difference between the two addresses in bytes.